# Internet Explorer 6 PNG Fix for background images

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png, transparency, background-image

Does anyone know a working PNG transparency fix for IE6 that also works on background images (of divs)? All that I tried (over 5) do not fix background images consistently. Adobe Browser Lab shows it's fixed but the target browsers still get that bluish transparency.

Thank you.

Comment: if you still have to write code for IE6, you have my sincere sympathies, especially if you're having to write code that doesn't already have all these little fixes in place already - iepngfix has been around for ever, so any IE6 site that doesn't have it is so horribly behind the times that it doesn't even bear thinking about.

Comment: I don't usually have to do this, but my client has support from Microsoft for IE6 and cannot upgrade without a new support contract. Tried pngfix from Twin-Helix but it only shows as fix in Adobe Browser Lab not real IE6 browser sadly.

Comment: FIX is a tag for different purpose than that of yours. Please don't put the wrong tags for your question.

Comment: I didn't mean to press rollback in the first place, sorry. And while you might be right about FIX tag in stackover flow, most people use that word when searching for `png fix` on search engines, but ok. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Comment: Hi, Lior. I have tried that before posting and 4 others including a jQuery one (v2) but all seem to fail at fixing the background problem. I think the biggest problem here is I cannot test on IE6 browsers often as I cannot have on installed here and Adobe Browser Lab gives me a good looking screenshot.